# How does Python's async kill signal handling (signal.signal) work?

Tags: python

Python has async kill signal handling:

```
import signal
import sys

def signal_handler(*_):
    print("\nExiting...")
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```

From what I understand, when Python receives the signal registered here, it stops doing whatever it was doing, and executes the signal handler. If the signal handler doesn't stop the program, when it returns, Python continues doing whatever it was doing.

Is this some sort of special case? It seems strange that something can just interrupt the main thread, make it jump to a complete different function (the signal handler), and then return to what it was doing when the handler returns. I've been programming in Python for a few years, and I'm not aware of anything else in Python that allows you to register a function that at some point just forces the main thread to temporarily do something else no matter what it was doing, before returning to it. Sure, Python has Async support, but you need to await things there before Python will switch what it is executing. The main thread here is not doing any kind of awaiting before focus is taken away from whatever it was doing.

I'm currently studying Rust. As far as I can tell, Rust has a few options for letting you handle kill signals, including:

- Running a background thread that watches for an incoming kill signal (like SIGINT), and sets a boolean for your main thread to check, and act on
- Running a background thread that watches for an incoming kill signal, and does something about it

Neither interrupt the main thread, and make it execute the signal handler before returning the main thread to what it was doing. This sounds like a Python-specific way to handle kill signals that is built into the interpreter itself, and only possible in a higher level language like Python, where you can have the interpreter run code in-between each line of user code it runs. Or am I wrong?

Comment: This isn't all that different from the OS-level signal handling facilities (which *also* interrupt a thread in the middle of whatever it's doing), or from a thread stopping what it's doing to run garbage collection when that gets triggered.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Interesting. Garbage collection is a special case. Sounds like this is another special case. I imagine there aren't too many times where the main thread gets interrupted like this, and I'm guessing this can't be user-defined (outside of kill signal handling).